# General solution of the ordinary differential equation $(D^4+D^2+1)y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(D^4+D^2+1)y=0$ where $D=\frac{d}{dx}$

$$D^4+D^2+1 =0 \Rightarrow D^4 + D^2 + \frac14 +\frac{{3}}{4} = 0 \Rightarrow (D^2 + \frac12) = \pm \frac{\sqrt{3\iota}}{2} \Rightarrow D^2 = \frac{-1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{3\iota}}{2} \Rightarrow D= \pm \sqrt{\frac{-1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{3\iota}}{2}} = \pm \sqrt{e^{\pm(2/3)\pi\iota}} = \pm e^{\pm(1/3)\pi\iota}  $$

Is there a way to simplify this?

Comment: Note: The $\frac34$ moves to the other side of the equation as a negative.

Comment: Corrected, thanks

Comment: This will be solved via De Moivre's then.

Comment: But now, $i$ should be outside the radical.

Comment: @SoLo: From the roots, we arrive at $$y(x) =  c_1 e^{-\frac{x}{2}} \sin \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}\right)+c_3 e^{x/2} \sin \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}\right)+c_2 e^{x/2} \cos \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}\right)+c_4 e^{-\frac{x}{2}} \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Find a and b $D^2=(a+bi)^2=a^2-b^2+i(2ab)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is
$$x^4+x^2+1=0$$
Let $y=x^2$, then we have that:
$$y^2+y+1=0$$
And the solution is $y=-\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$, or in exponential form: $y_1=e^{\frac{2}{3}i\pi}$ and $y_2=e^{-\frac{2}{3}i\pi}$. And from $x^2=y$, we get that $x_{12}=\exp\left(\frac{\frac{2}{3}i\pi+2ni \pi}{2}\right)$ and $x_{34}=\exp\left(\frac{-\frac{2}{3}i\pi+2ni \pi}{2}\right)$ for $n=0$ and $n=1$. So the roots are:
$$x_1=\exp\left(\frac{1}{3}i \pi\right)$$
$$x_2=\exp\left(\frac{4}{3}i \pi\right)$$
$$x_3=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{3}i \pi\right)=\exp\left(\frac{5}{3}i \pi\right)$$
$$x_4=\exp\left(\frac{2}{3}i \pi\right)$$

Comment: Alternatively, since $x^6 - 1 = (x^2 - 1)(x^4 + x^2 + 1)$, the solutions of the auxiliary equation $x^4 + x^2 + 1$ are precisely the sixth roots of unity ($\exp(k \cdot 2 \pi i  / 6)$, $k = 0, \ldots, 5$) that are not square roots of unity ($\pm 1$), that is, $\exp (k \pi i / 3)$, $k = 1, 2, 4, 5$.

Comment: @Travis Nice solution, I've never seen it before!

Answer (score 0):

The roots of $\lambda^4+\lambda^2+1$ are $$ \lambda_1=\frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\ \lambda_2=\frac{1}{2} - i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\ \lambda_3=-\frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\ \lambda_4=-\frac{1}{2} - i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} $$ 
Thus, the solution to the ODE is 
$$ y(x) = \sum_{k=1}^4 a_k\exp(x\lambda_k) $$
If we write $\mu_{1,2} = \pm\Re(\lambda_1), \sigma = \Im(\lambda_1)$, then
$$ y(x) = \sum_{k=1}^2 [b_k\cos(x\sigma) + c_k\sin(x\sigma)]\exp(x\mu_k) $$